# Cannot Resolve PictureInPictureParams

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, picture-in-picture

Trying to set up some enhanced PIP functionality. Getting stuck on declaring this variable:

```
/** The arguments to be used for Picture-in-Picture mode. */
    private final PictureInPictureParams.Builder mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder =
            new PictureInPictureParams.Builder();
```

I have an import at the top of the class:

```
import android.app.PictureInPictureParams;
```

but this has a compile error:

Cannot Resolve PictureInPictureParams

In my build.gradle file, I have these two lines:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0'
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this dependency? Thank you.

Comment: It should work, or you might think the `api` required 26++ a unresolved class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 26 or higher.

Comment: I am using ```compileSdkVersion 27``` but I have the same issue.

Comment: If you are getting "Cannot Resolve PictureInPictureParams" for `import android.app.PictureInPictureParams`, either you do not have `compileSdkVersion 26` or higher, or your development environment is really really broken. `PictureInPictureParams` [was added in API Level 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PictureInPictureParams). [Here is an activity that imports it successfully](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.13/MultiWindow/PiP/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/recyclerview/videolist/VideoPlayerActivity.java).